# Find the no of days between 2 date?

Tags: angularjs, controller

How can i calculate the number of days between 2 dates.1st date is the date fetching from the database and the 2nd date is todays date.

```
     $scope.remainingbalance=function(sintrst){           
            $http({
                    url:"php/selectREMAININGBALACE.php",
                    method:"GET",
                    params:{GLID:$scope.cstmrdetails.GLID}
                    })
                    .success(function(tilldate){
                     $scope.tilldate=tilldate;  //date fetching from the database
                    $scope.difference=$scope.tilldate[0].TILLDATE-$scope.date;//$scope.date is todays date
                     console.log( $scope.difference);
                     });

                  }
```

`console.log( $scope.difference)`shows `NaN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **moment.js** you can use the [**`diff`**](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) function.

```
var a = moment();
var b = moment(tilldate);
var result = a.diff(b, 'days');
```

Comment: Simple and efficient.